# Particle System error with Depth of Field

Tags: rendering, particles, eevee-render-engine, depth-of-field

I'm trying to make a shot in a grassy field with a DoF effect but the grass particle system is having errors with it. I've outlined where it's visible. The DoF focus is just in front of the radio. [image]

I should also add that I used CG Geek's tutorial of making grass in 2.8, maybe that has something to do with it, idk.

Comment: How does the z channel look like? Btw: please read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Where can I see what the Z Channel looks like?